# How to modify the default top navigation bar style in flutter

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar

I want to make a top navigation bar with this effect, but it's very difficult to modify the default tab style of tabcontroller! Then I try to use container to modify it by myself. It's very simple, but the problem is that I can't support left and right swiping to switch pages. Because the gesture has been blocked by pageview. So in the end, I think it's better to use the tab provided by the system and then modify the style, some one help me!

[image]
[image]

```
DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The indicator property of TabBar can be used to achieve the look.
In your case, try this-

```
DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottom: Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        width: 200,
        child:TabBar(
        labelColor: Colors.red,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: Colors.white),
        tabs: [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: thanks for you tip，preferedSize is work,but app bar child must be a PreferredSize widget.

Answer (score 0):

my code is here

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: PreferredSize(
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                color: Color(0xfff0f4f7)),
            width: 193,
            height: 36,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: ThemeColor,
                  unselectedLabelColor: MainTextColor,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(
                        child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: Container(
                          width: 95,
                          child: Text(
                            "transfer_upload_list".tr,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          )),
                    )),
                    Tab(
                        child: Container(
                      width: 95,
                      child: Text(
                        "transfer_download_list".tr,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    )),
                  ]),
            )),
        preferredSize: Size(193, 36),
      )),
    ));
```